# How to separate gmail message from phpmailer contact form

Tags: php, forms, gmail, phpmailer, contact-form

I am making website and I created contact us form using phpmailer which send them on gmail address. But no matter what I fill into form, gmail always put them as if from one receiver - its stacking them into one chat. Even when reply-to mail-address is different. Is there any way how to fix this.

Screenshot from gmail

[image: 1]

PHP code

```
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$myAwardSpaceEmail = "info@email.sk";
$myAwardSpaceEmailPassword = "password";
$myPersonalEmail = "email@gmail.com";

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

    $mail->Host = 'webpage.sk';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = $myAwardSpaceEmail;
    $mail->Password = $myAwardSpaceEmailPassword;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;

    $mail->setFrom($myAwardSpaceEmail, 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress($myPersonalEmail);
    $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);

    $mail->isHTML(true);    
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mail->Body = nl2br("Meno:"."\n".$_POST['name']."\n\n"."Telefón:"."\n".$_POST['phone']."\n\n"."Lokalita:"."\n".$_POST['address']."\n\n"."Správa:"."\n".$_POST['message']);


    $recaptcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $res = reCaptcha($recaptcha);
    if($res['success']){
        try {
            $mail->send();
            echo 'Your message was sent successfully!';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Your message could not be sent! PHPMailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
        }
    }else{
        echo "There is a problem with the kontakt.html document!";
    }
}


function reCaptcha($recaptcha){
    $secret = "security_code";
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  
    $postvars = array("secret"=>$secret, "response"=>$recaptcha, "remoteip"=>$ip);
    $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
  
    return json_decode($data, true);
  }
```

HTML code

```
<form method="POST" action="kontakt.php">
                        <label for="firstName">Meno</label><br/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Kontaktny formular SAFI nabytok" size="30" placeholder="Priezvisko" required>
                        <br/>
                        <label for="name">Meno</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="name" size="30" placeholder="Priezvisko" required>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <label for="email">E-mail:</label><br/>
                        <input type="email" name="email" size="30" placeholder="vzor@mail.sk" required>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <label for="phone">Telefónne číslo</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" size="30" placeholder="0911000222 / +421911000222" required>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <label for="address">Miesto realizácie projektu</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="address" size="30" placeholder="Bratislava - Petržalka" required>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <label for="message">Message:</label><br/>
                        <textarea rows="9" name="message" cols="30" placeholder="Vaša správa"></textarea>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="g-recaptcha" style="display: inline-block;" data-sitekey="site_code"></div>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Odoslať" name="submit">
                        
                    </form>
```

Comment: They're all from the same sender, so what gmail does is logical. Of course, you can change the general settings in your gmail so it never stacks emails into chats, or maybe you can make some custom rules to put them in different folders or something. You can't do much from the PHP side though, this is about the behaviour of the gmail client application.

Comment: yes it's from one sender because my hosting server which I use has strict policy with sending emails. Only option is using phpmailer and even then you must use different mail as gmail because its blocked so I used domain mail as brigde between gmail account and website.

So what you are saiyng it's not option to separate it only in gmail settings ?

Comment: No, I said the only options you have are by changing the gmail settings. You cannot do anything from PHP.

Comment: `my hosting server which I use has strict policy with sending emails`...and this is probably the correct thing to do, unless you want all your emails to appear as spam or spoofing and be rejected by the receivers!